# send view in email body mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, email, viewresult

I want to send a view in email body in mvc.
please guide how to render view so that it can be sent as html email body.

thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider using something like [ActionMailer](https://bitbucket.org/swaj/actionmailer.net/wiki/Home). You can download it using [NuGet](http://nuget.codeplex.com/).

Comment: link is down: "That link has no power here" - neither links are working

Answer (score 0):

string path = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ProjectPath"] ;
string gmailpath = path + "/" + "Driver/VerificedAccount?code=" + root.Result.EmailVerificationCode;

```
                var body= "<html><body><p></p><p><a href = "+gmailpath+" > Please click  Verifed  Account   </a></p></body></html> ";
```

var st = EmailclassHtml(sendemail.Email, "Verification-Driver", body);

public string EmailclassHtml(string email, string subjectname, string messgae)
{

```
        string ownemail = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SenderEmail"];
        string ownname = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SenderName"];
        string returnmessage = "success";

        var senderEmail = new MailAddress(ownemail, ownname);
        var receiverEmail = new MailAddress(email, "Receiver");
        var password = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SenderPassword"];
        var sub = subjectname;
        var body = messgae;

        var smtp = new SmtpClient
        {
            Host = "smtp.gmail.com",
            Port = 587,

            EnableSsl = true,
            DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network,
            UseDefaultCredentials = true,
            Credentials = new NetworkCredential(senderEmail.Address, password)

        };
        using (var mess = new MailMessage(senderEmail, receiverEmail)
        {
            Subject = sub,
            Body = body,
            IsBodyHtml = true
        })

            try
            {
                smtp.Send(mess);
                return returnmessage;
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                returnmessage = "fail";

            }
        return returnmessage;
    }
```

Comment: Please edit your question to include some description to your code

Comment: Please check out the [formatting help page](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) to improve the formatting in your answer, and also check out [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) to improve your answer.